# replace in regex baed on repetition index

Tags: java, regex, replace

I have string which contains a specific sub-string multiple times. I want to replace odd repetition indices with `st1` and even ones with `st2` in JAVA. For example, assume my original string is:

```
ihuiHIdasodkiokedwiHIkopkoijiojiojHIiojiodjadjaiojijHIjoiji
```

and the searching sub-string is `HI`. Replacing string for odd repetitions is `T` and for even ones is `Y`. The output should be:

```
ihuiTdasodkiokedwiYkopkoijiojiojTiojiodjadjaiojijYjoiji
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Use a `Pattern` and `Matcher` combination with a `StringBuffer` to replace terms into, as well as a flag for even vs odd occurrences.

Comment: @Mena, I'm new to JAVA; would you please post an answer with sample code?

Comment: What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3):

You can replace them by pair and then handle separately the case where there's an odd number of occurences.

```
String input = "ihuiHIdasodkiokedwiHIkopkoijiojiojHIiojiodjadjaiojijHIjoiji";
String result = input.replaceAll("HI(.*?)HI", "T$1Y")
                     .replace("HI", "T");
```